# Case of "it": "Be it ever so humble"

Tags: grammatical-case

As you know, there's a saying going:

> Be it ever so humble, there's no place like home.

I'm having difficulty in identifying the case of *it* in the sentence. Here are reasons why.

1. *Be it ever so humble*, as it is a clause, I think it needs a subject and so *it* is subjective.
2. *Be it ever so humble*, I also think that since this is in imperative mood, I guess it doesn't really need a subject, and *it* is accusative.

Which one is it: accusative or subjective?

Comment: _be it ever so humble_ is not imperative. It means _even though it's very humble_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *be* is a copula, so traditionally it does not have an object, but rather a subject complement as a secondary argument.

However, in your example, the word *it* is simply the **subject**; the reason why it looks odd is *inversion*: verb and subject have switched position. This can happen in certain kinds of subordinate clauses that lack a conjunction, especially if their verb is in the subjunctive mood. Here *be* is a present subjunctive, not an imperative.

> Should he leave the premises, please arrest him.

This is another example of a subordinate clause without a conjunction but with inversion, in the past subjunctive (*should*).

*Ever so humble* is the subject complement.